# carrierwaver doesn't save image in postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, postgresql, carrierwave

Hi guys I'm using carrierwave on my rails app to upload images from the computer to create new items.. If I create the item without uploading an image, the item will be saved into the database, otherwise it won't. So there's must be something wrong with my settings for the carrierwave. can anyone give me an hand, identifing the mistake(s)?

FORM HTML

```
 <form action="/items" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>

  <%= hidden_field_tag :authenticity_token, form_authenticity_token %>
  <label>Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="name">

  <label>Size</label>
  <input type="text" name="size">

  <label>Image</label>
  <input type="file" name="image">

  <label>Description</label>
  <textarea name="description"></textarea>

  <label>Price</label>
  <input type="number" name="price" placeholder="price $$">

   <button> Save </button>

</form>
```

IMAGE UPLOADER

```
  class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

   include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

   storage :file

   def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
   end

   version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_fit => [150, 150]
   end


   def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
   end
 end
```

GEM INSTALLED

```
   gem 'carrierwave'

   gem "mini_magick"
```

ITEM MODEL

```
 class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

    belongs_to :category

 end
```

ITEM CONTROLLER

```
 class ItemsController < ApplicationController

     def index
       @items = Item.all
     end

     def create
      item = Item.new
      item.name = params[:name]
      item.image = params[:image]
      item.size = params[:size]
      item.description = params[:description]
      item.price = params[:price]
      if item.save
        render :show
      else
        puts "error"
      end
    end

 def show
  @item = Item.find(params[:id])
 end

 def update
   @item = Item.find(params[:id])
   @item.name = params[:name]
   @item.image = params[:image]
   @item.size = params[:size]
   @item.description = params[:description]
   @item.price = params[:price]
 end

 def destroy
   @item = Item.find(params[:id])
   @item.destroy
  end
end
```

Comment: Add your controller code

Comment: add your item model code .

Comment: What is wriiten on your log file while save after uploading an image?

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
<form action="/items" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
```

to this one:

```
<%= form_for Item.new, method: 'post', multipart=> true  do %>
```

Don't forget to close the `<%= form_for %>` **end** tag. Hope this will help. 
It'll be helpful if you can post the `development.log` file output.

N.B. Please reformat your code. This is the most irritating code ever.